# How can I transfer eth from an account wallet to a smart contract

Tags: solidity

I'm creating a smart contract that allows people to pay for a monthly subscription

I got stacked in this :

how to transfer plan.amount from the user wallet to the smart contract?

```
function subscribe(uint planId) external {
    Plan storage plan = plans[planId];
    require(plan.merchant != address(0), 'address not valid');

    bool sent = payable(address(this)).send(plan.amount);
        require(sent, "tx failed");
 
    emit PaymentSent(
      msg.sender, 
      plan.merchant,
      plan.amount, // the monthly amount for Subscription
      planId, 
      block.timestamp
    );


    subscriptions[msg.sender][planId] = Subscription(
      msg.sender,
      block.timestamp, 
      block.timestamp + 4 weeks // next payement
    );
    emit SubscriptionCreated(msg.sender, planId, block.timestamp);
  }
```

Comment: Can you share all your smart contract code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `subscribe()` function needs to use the `payable` modifier in order to accept ETH. Then you can validate how much the user has sent while invoking your function with the `msg.value` global variable.

It's not possible to request a specific amount from the contract, as the contract code is executed **after** the user has sent the transaction. You always need to validate how much has the user sent along with the transaction invoking the function.

```
function subscribe(uint planId) external payable {
    // revert if the sent value is not expected
    require(msg.value == 1 ether, "You need to send 1 ETH");
}
```

However you can control the predefined value on the UI, while creating the transaction request to their MetaMask or other wallet.

```
await window.ethereum.request(
    method: 'eth_sendTransaction',
    [
        from: userAddress,
        to: yourContract,
        data: <invoking the subscribe() function>,
        value: <1 ETH in wei, in hex>
    ]
);
```

Docs: https://docs.metamask.io/guide/ethereum-provider.html#ethereum-request-args