# How to consume msg.value?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I understand `msg.value` represents how much wei the sender sent.  But how does a contract use it?

In the example of a vending machine, the contract checks to ensure enough `msg.value` is present to cover the cupcakes ordered, but there's no code that actually deducts the wei.

Example:
https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/smart-contracts/#a-digital-vending-machine

I do see some info about buyer and `seller.transfer()` here:
https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.15/solidity-by-example.html#safe-remote-purchase

Answer (score 1):

Typically, this code is paired with a dapp front-end for the user to operate, so if you are a developer who wants to send ETH when calling a contract, I recommend doing this

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking to understand how the contract itself uses the msg.value!

Answer (score 1):

A contract has no need for deducting to receive ETH or `msg.value`. The sender will determine ETH payment amount.

ETH receiving contract only need `payable` modifier to indicate that it can receive ETH. We can say it is like a vending machine in the way that the contract cannot determine how much it will receive, but you can refund by transferring the exceeding ETH back to the sender.

Unlike ERC20 which works differently, it does needs to be approved and deducted for the general contract purchase function.

Read more:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/71883390/2017851
- https://medium.com/coinmonks/solidity-transfer-vs-send-vs-call-function-64c92cfc878a
- https://cryptomarketpool.com/reentrancy-attack-in-a-solidity-smart-contract/